# factor theorem for multivariables

Tags: polynomials, factoring

My understanding of the remainder theorem for one variable is that for $$f(x)=(x-a)q(x)+r(x)$$$\qquad$ if $x=a\implies f(a)=0\times q(a)+r(a)$ so $f(a)=r(a)$
Is this correct for a multivariate function? $$f(x,y,z)=(x-g(y,z))(y-h(x,z))(z-i(x,y))q(x,y,z)+r(x,y,z)$$so $x=g(y,z)\implies f(g(y,z))=r(x,y,z)$ thanks for any help.

Comment: No, the set of multivariate polynomials over $\Bbb R$, or any field, is not euclidean i.e. there is no division algorithm similar to the integers or polynomials of one variable.

Comment: There *is* a division algorithm for multivariate polynomials, but it's not exactly a euclidean algorithm, and it's more complex. You divide by `a set of polynomials` and the rest of the division is unique only if the set of polynomials is ‘well chosen’ in a certain sense, leading to the concept of a `Gröbner basis`.

Comment: @Bernard That's why I said `similar to the integers`. Anyway, I guess the question is now whether said algorithm interacts in any special way with substitution?

Comment: Thanks for comments so far.  By division algorithm do you mean algebraic long division? I hadn't thought about how the remainder theorem can come from that.  I looked at the Grobner basis but it was beyond my understanding if I'm honest.

Comment: Perhaps this is what you're looking for: [Factor theorem for multiple variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2667635), [Proof of the single factor theorem over an arbitrary commutative ring](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/664825). (This came up in connection with an answer to your question "[Factorise a matrix using the factor theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1090570)" - as you can see [in this chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/13473/2019/6/26).)